# почему vulkan api не видит двух моих видеокарт?

Tags: c++, vulkan

```
unsigned int enumeratePhysDevice;
vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(vkInstance, &enumeratePhysDevice, nullptr);
std::cout << enumeratePhysDevice << std::endl;
physicalDevice.resize(enumeratePhysDevice);
vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(vkInstance, &enumeratePhysDevice, physicalDevice.data());
```

не могу понять почему vulkan не видит двух моих видеокарт хотя обе поддерживают их. вот какие у меня видеокарты:

1. intel graphics 620;
2. geforce mx150;
   диспетчер задач так же показывает что есть 2 видеокарты
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите пожалуйста что я не так делаю?
могу показать как я инициализировал дескриптор vulkan, если надо

Comment: то есть enumeratePhysDevice пустой?

Comment: Код который возвращается из функции вызова vulkan вы смотрели? Если нет, то смотрите что он возвращает... И желательно добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: нет он видит только одну видеокарту, хотя должен видеть две

Comment: Вы код возврата функции проверяйте... Ещё раз, что возвращает функция? Если не скажите что там, НИЧЕГО УГАДАТЬ НЕ ВЫЙДЕТ.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938011/vulkan-sdk-detects-only-1-gpu-at-a-time

Comment: функция vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices возвращает   VK_SUCCESS, могу прикрепить скрин и предоставить код